# How to use Array and branching in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, branch

I have problem with diskon.

```
if (totkes > 100000)   
 diskon = 0.1; 
else
 diskon = 0.05
```

I input it with `totkes > 100000` but this program show diskon is `0.05`, it should be `0.1`. How to fix it? I really need your help guys.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      String[] nama = new String[100];
      int[] harga = new int[100];
      int[] item = new int [100];
      String day=" ";
      int jml;
      int hari;
      String ptg = "";
      double diskon = 0;
      double total=0;
      double totkes =0;
      double totbay = 0;
      System.out.println("1. Senin - Jumat");
      System.out.println("2. Sabtu");
      System.out.println("3. Minggu");
      System.out.print("Masukan Pilihan : ");
      hari = input.nextInt();
          if (hari==1) {
              day= "Senin - Jumat";
              if (totkes > 100000){
                 diskon = 0.1; 
                 ptg = "10%";
              } else {
                  diskon = 0.05;
                  ptg = "5%";
              }
          } else if (hari==2){
              day= "Sabtu";
              if (totkes>100000){
                 diskon = 0.15; 
                 ptg = "15%";
              } else {
                  diskon = 0.1;
                  ptg = "10%";
              }
          }else if (hari == 3){
              day= "Minggu";
              if (totkes >100000){
                 diskon = 0.2; 
                 ptg = "20%";
              } else {
                  diskon = 0.15;
                  ptg = "15%";
              }
          }else {
              System.out.print("Maaf, inputan anda salah!");
          }
      System.out.print("Masukan Jumlah Barang Yang Diinputkan : ");
      jml = input.nextInt();
      for (int i=0; i<jml; i++) {
          System.out.println("Data ke-"+(i+1));
          System.out.print("Nama Barang   : ");
          nama[i] = input.next();
          System.out.print("Harga         : ");
          harga[i] = input.nextInt();
          System.out.print("Jumlah Barang : ");
          item[i] = input.nextInt();   

      }

      System.out.println("| No | Nama Barang | Harga | Jumlah | Total |");
      for (int i=0; i<jml; i++) {
          System.out.print("   "+(i+1));
          System.out.print("   "+nama[i]);
          System.out.print("       "+harga[i]);
          System.out.print("      "+item[i]);
         // System.out.print("        "+ptg);
          System.out.println("    "+(total = harga[i]*item[i]));   

          totkes=totkes+total;
          totbay=totkes - (totkes*diskon);

      }
      System.out.println(" Hari:       "+day);


       System.out.println("Total Keseluruhan: "+totkes);
       System.out.println("Diskon: "+diskon);
       System.out.println("Diskon: "+ptg);
      System.out.println("Total Bayar : "+totbay);


    }
}
```

Comment: when **`hari == 2`** and `totkes > 100000` you will get the desired result.

Comment: You're never getting a value from the user for `totkes`

Comment: I've just tried it but still same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make calculation outside loop.

```
 System.out.println("Hari              : "+day);
    System.out.println("Total             : Rp."+totkes);
    System.out.println("Diskon            : Rp."+ptgn);
    ptg = totkes * diskon;
    System.out.println("Total Bayar       : Rp."+(totbay = totkes-ptg));
```

Answer (score 1):

The following lines are executed once:

```
if (hari==1) {
      day= "Senin - Jumat";
      if (totkes > 100000){
         diskon = 0.1; 
         ptg = "10%";
      } else {
          diskon = 0.05;
          ptg = "5%";
      }
  } else if (hari==2){
      day= "Sabtu";
      if (totkes>100000){
         diskon = 0.15; 
         ptg = "15%";
      } else {
          diskon = 0.1;
          ptg = "10%";
      }
  }else if (hari == 3){
      day= "Minggu";
      if (totkes >100000){
         diskon = 0.2; 
         ptg = "20%";
      } else {
          diskon = 0.15;
          ptg = "15%";
      }
  }else {
      System.out.print("Maaf, inputan anda salah!");
  }
```

And in the above part diskon will be 0.05 only because the value of totkes is 0 as set in the following initial lines:

```
double diskon = 0;
double total=0;
double totkes =0;
double totbay = 0;
```

You might have mistakenly put the if, else if ladder for setting the diskon value outside the below for loop:

```
System.out.println("| No | Nama Barang | Harga | Jumlah | Total |");
for (int i=0; i<jml; i++) {
  System.out.print("   "+(i+1));
  System.out.print("   "+nama[i]);
  System.out.print("       "+harga[i]);
  System.out.print("      "+item[i]);
 // System.out.print("        "+ptg);
  System.out.println("    "+(total = harga[i]*item[i]));   

  totkes=totkes+total;
  totbay=totkes - (totkes*diskon);

}
System.out.println(" Hari:       "+day);
```

Comment: I don't put diskon inside loop because hari is not array. I input hari just for once.

Answer (score 0):

you have initialised "**totkes**" as 0. So, it is always going to be 0.5 per your "if" logic. did you intend to get user input for totkes?

Comment: this program will error if I don't initialize totkes as 0.

Comment: your program is doing what you ask it to do. Either you get user input for totkes or initialise totkes value other than 0.  your condition is if (totkes greater than 100000) which is always false as you initialise value as 0.

Comment: sorry viku,, the problem of this program is not totkes but diskon. Please check the output of the program  here
http://s1115.photobucket.com/user/sufifi/media/tanya_zps59db35d6.png.html?sort=3&o=0

Answer (score 0):

@ sufi - Try below and see if that what you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      String[] nama = new String[100];
      int[] harga = new int[100];
      int[] item = new int [100];
      String day=" ";
      int jml;
      int hari;
      String ptg = "";
      double diskon =0;
      double total = 0;
      double totkes = 0;
      double totbay;
      System.out.println("1. Senin - Jumat");
      System.out.println("2. Sabtu");
      System.out.println("3. Minggu");
      System.out.print("Masukan Pilihan : ");
      System.out.println("Hari:");

      hari = input.nextInt();

      if (hari > 3 && hari <= 0){
          System.out.println("Sorry: ");
      }

      else if (hari == 1){
          day = "Senin - Jumat";

      }
      else if (hari == 2){
          day = "Sabtu";

      }
      else if (hari == 3){
          day = "Minggu";

      }
      else {

      }

      System.out.print("Masukan Jumlah Barang Yang Diinputkan : ");
      jml = input.nextInt();
      for (int i=0; i<jml; i++) {
          System.out.println("Data ke-"+(i+1));
          System.out.print("Nama Barang   : ");
          nama[i] = input.next();
          System.out.print("Harga         : ");
          harga[i] = input.nextInt();
          System.out.print("Jumlah Barang : ");
          item[i] = input.nextInt();   

      }




      System.out.println("| No | Nama Barang | Harga | Jumlah | Total |");
      for (int i=0; i<jml; i++) {
          System.out.print("   "+(i+1));
          System.out.print("   "+nama[i]);
          System.out.print("       "+harga[i]);
          System.out.print("      "+item[i]);
         // System.out.print("        "+ptg);
          System.out.println("    "+(total = harga[i]*item[i]));   

      }
          totkes = totkes + total;




          if (hari == 1 && totkes > 100000){
              diskon = 0.1; 
              ptg = "10%";
          }else if (hari == 1 && totkes < 100000){
              diskon = 0.05;
               ptg = "5%";
          }else if (hari ==2 && totkes > 100000){
              diskon = 0.15; 
              ptg = "15%";
          }else if (hari == 2 && totkes < 100000){
              diskon = 0.1;
               ptg = "10%";
          }else if (hari == 3 && totkes > 100000){
              diskon = 0.2; 
              ptg = "20%";
          }else if (hari == 3 && totkes < 100000){
              diskon = 0.15;
               ptg = "15%";
          }



          totbay = totkes - (totkes * diskon);

      System.out.println(" Hari:       "+day);
      System.out.println("Total Keseluruhan: "+totkes);
      System.out.println("Diskon: "+diskon);
      System.out.println("Diskon: "+ptg);
      System.out.println("Total Bayar : "+totbay);



}
```